# Are questions about solving practical data science problems (memory etc.) on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, datascience-stackexchange

Are questions like [How to resolve Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.1 GB for glmnet in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329796/how-to-resolve-error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-1-1-gb-for-glmnet-in-r?noredirect=1) on topic? On one hand, it asks about software, on another, this is about solving a practical data science problem and has general, software-agnostic, solutions (algorithms working in online mode etc.). Or maybe we should migrate it to datascience.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I think if questions like this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2806 are on topic then this one can also be considered on topic. It would benefit from some editing though which I tried to do now.

Comment: To me questions on general statistical computing  are usually fine; questions on specific code usually not. A rule of thumb is to imagine the question without specific code references. If little or nothing is left, it is often off-topic. If something of wide interest is left, it is on-topic. A related test is whether a question focusing on software X should be almost equally interesting to people who use Y or Z instead. Why do different programs give different results is a kind of question to which the answer is often statistical.

Comment: I imagine that this question has different angles and is in the gray area (so I'd say it is on topic). Somebody is looking for a hack to allocate some vector. This might be done in two different ways, considering mathematical/computational tricks, or considering software engineering tricks. In the discussion we see both (discussion about memory allocation and about changing the strategy to get to the solution).

Comment: That question is very clearly off topic--but for a completely different reason: it doesn't supply enough information to permit a diagnosis.  We couldn't send it to any other SE site because of that.  For example, if this is a Gaussian response with linear link, there are potential ways to reduce RAM requirements by working only with the sums-of-squares matrix, but if it is for a GLM (say, a logistic regression) then such an option is off the table.

Comment: @whuber This information has been provided by the OP in an edit.

Comment: If you think the problem can be resolved in software agnostic manner, then you can help OP to reformulate the question in such a way that makes it software agnostic instead of outright closing or porting the question to SE

Answer (score 5):

I think that question, as currently framed, should be considered off topic.

The way I think about this is really pretty simple: I ask myself what the OP needs explained.  If the answer is something about code / software, then it's off topic; if it's something about statistics / machine learning, then it's on topic, even if the question is asked in terms of some particular software (and may not even be askable without reference to software).  It is true that the latter condition can mean that a given question cannot be answered by people who don't use that software, and may not even be understandable by them, but because the answer is an explanation of a statistical concept, it is ultimately a statistical question, and thus on-topic.

It's true that the specific thread at issue includes the line, "Or if you can recommend another way to proceed with the variable selection that would also work for me?", which may have been intended in a software-neutral way, but this seems like an afterthought.  If the question were rephrased to ask about general computational strategies for large datasets, or about variable selection, then it would become on-topic, in my opinion.  It would be fine if the question still makes reference to software as part of providing informative context for their situation.  But the OP needs to show that they are clear that they are asking a statistical / software-neutral question, and that they will be happy with a sufficiently clear statistical answer, even if it were illustrated with, say, minitab.  If the OP would not be OK with that, then they are not asking a question that is appropriate for this site.

With regard to migrating the thread to datascience.SE, I suppose that would be possible, but it probably isn't something that I would do.  It is true that DS handles questions concerning topics related to the domains of CV and SO, but which would be off-topic on those sites for various reasons.  In that light, the thread may be OK there, so I'm not necessarily opposed.  It just isn't something that would even occur to me, to be honest.

Comment: +1. Do you think the current version of this question (after several edits) can be considered on-topic?

Comment: @amoeba, IMO no. It is still asking about R code, how it works, how to use it to get around the error. It does not seem to be asking about the related statistical issues, nor does it seem to be asking about a computational algorithm (to be implemented later in some barely mentioned language) as w/ the PCA thread you linked to above.

Comment: Hmm. OK. I edited it again (only slightly) - can you check if it's okay now?

Comment: @amoeba, from the body of the Q, the main question seems to be, "Is there some package that I can use...". Ie, no, this is still off-topic from my point of view. As I discuss above, my definition is based on what the OP needs explained, & they seem to be after R code / packages, or more generally an R based solution. Another way to test whether a Q is on topic (which is imperfect, but often clarifying) is to imagine someone answers w/ an example coded in software to which the OP does not have access, would that be a sufficient answer for the OP? If not, the Q is off topic.

Comment: In this case, 'try package y in software z' is the kind of answer the OP seems to want, but will only be of value if the OP has access to software z. That's b/c the OP is asking about code, not statistics.

Comment: I can see your logic but I'd say it's too restrictive. Somebody wants to run logistic regression with elastic net penalty -- a very clear & meaningful statistical problem. The dataset is too large and the standard tool (glmnet) fails to work -- a very clear obstacle that other people can later have too. This person comes to our forum and asks "What do do?!" -- and we are telling them: Sorry, off-topic. This just looks strange to me.

Comment: @amoeba, I think these kinds of clear boundaries are the only thing that's workable in the long run. People who need tech support for their software need to use the software's native facilities.

Comment: I agree with the second sentence, but in this case the Q is explicitly not about the tech support with glmnet. As I wrote above, the Q is basically "What can I do?". You can say that it's about package recommendation, and you will have a point. But it's definitely not tech support.

Comment: They can ask, 'what can I do?', but 'what code / package do I use?' is off topic. There is a difference between those. It may be subtle, but it's clear to me.

Comment: Wait - so "what can I do?" is on-topic then? Because the title, the 1st paragraph and the last sentence amount to that I think. Or if you think not, then a tiniest of edits could make it amount to that.

Comment: I could edit the question to make it about 'what can I do?', but it would be a *large* edit. It isn't my place to change the nature of the OP's question. Moreover, I think the answer to that question would not be an answer the OP would find helpful, b/c the OP is *clearly* after, '`library(z); mod <- y(data); summary(y)`'.

Comment: If *the OP* changes their Q to be clearly about something else. That would indicate that another type of answer would suffice. In that case, I'd be happy to reopen.

Comment: OK I will stop editing that Q now, but if *I* were the OP, I would still not know what exactly kind of edit you would want from me.

Comment: Perhaps the clearest strategy would be to remove all reference to software, packages, error messages, etc. Then state that you want to know what strategies or algorithms are available for penalized LR when the matrix is too large to fit in a reasonable computer's memory. That is more drastic than necessary, but it does lay out a clear path forward. If the OP would not be interested in the answer to that kind of Q, the Q they are asking is off topic here.

Comment: OK but if this Q had not even mentioned glmnet, then my first comment would be along the lines of "Have you already tried glmnet? Did it not work?" It seems strange to *require* to edit this useful information out.

Comment: I'm with @amoeba on this one. It's an interesting Statistics problem, which just can't be solved without a computer, and which would be very hard to solve without using a dedicated software tool. The OP is not asking us to debug her code (as a matter of fact, she provides very little code at all), and there are at least two answers which work in R. The simplest answer is to broadly describe the implementation of the methodology which solves her problem, and then point her at the right package. The hardest, less useful answer is to describe the implementation in minute detail, don't mention 1/

Comment: 2/ the existing package and expecting her to reinvent the wheel. Then there are other approaches based on free cloud computing resources. I think it's an interesting, answerable question of general interest, and closing it is a pity. But of course that's just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @DeltaIV. I suggest you vote to reopen. I cannot because I already did and the Q did get reopened but then was closed by gung again; the system does not allow me to vote again. One of us should probably also post an answer here explaining our disagreement with gung.

Comment: @DeltaIV Well I could not resist a procrastination opportunity and did post an answer here.

Comment: @DeltaIV, see my comments under amoeba's answer. I certainly don't think that the algorithm needs to be described in "minute detail" & the fact that it is already implemented be intentionally left unsaid, in order for this to be on-topic. I think the answer you suggest would be fine. I just don't think the OP is after that. If I thought they were, I would reopen.

Comment: Here are two recent threads ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/329243/), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/329527/)) that are asked in terms of software (& people had voted to close), that I thought were ultimately statistical & voted to leave open. My point is that it isn't about whether code is included in the Q, but the nature of the appropriate answer. Those 2 were judgment calls, & I may have been wrong. Likewise, the thread under discussion here is also a judgment call, & I may be wrong again. What I am trying to do in this meta thread is clarify how I think about these issues.

Answer (score 3):

I have initially thought that I agree with @gung (and even upvoted his answer) but the discussion in the comments showed that I actually disagree.

**I think this question (after the clarifying edits) is on-topic.**

@Gung writes:

> If the question were rephrased to ask about general computational strategies for large datasets, or about variable selection, then it would become on-topic, in my opinion. It would be fine if the question still makes reference to software as part of providing informative context for their situation.

I think this is what *already* happened. The OP wants to run logistic regression with elastic net penalty -- a very clear & meaningful statistical setup. The dataset is too large and the standard tool (`glmnet`) fails to work -- a very clear obstacle. This person comes to our forum and essentially asks: "What can I do?". This *must* be on-topic.

@Gung replies that

> In this case, 'try package y in software z' is the kind of answer the OP seems to want

and I agree but I do not think this makes it off-topic. Imagine there *is* a more efficient algorithm of fitting this model that does not require so much memory. An answer describing this algorithm without mentioning the software package is pretty much useless because *nobody* wants to re-implement stuff like that from scratch. Everybody would want to have a working implementation.

Of course an answer "try package y in software z" and nothing else would be a bad answer. But a possibility of bad answer does not make the question off-topic. A description of the methodology *plus* a package recommendation would be a fine answer.

Comment: It's still off-topic to me, `"I have tried to use sparse matrix and it reduces the size from 2.2 to 1.1 GB, but I am still not able to run the function. Is there some package that I can use - I saw bigmemory but am not really sure how to apply it? Or if you can recommend another way to proceed with the variable selection that would also work for me?"`. But I think software/package recommendations have their place here on CV, so I also do not fully agree with gung.

Comment: @Firebug Can you clarify what aspect makes it off-topic and what kind of edit could make it on-topic? If OP cuts out the first two sentences of the part you quoted, will it become any better?

Comment: I think a discussion that illuminates the statistical & computational issues that led to the OPs result, & a "description of the methodology" that addresses the above, would be a great answer. Of course, there is no problem w/ pairing such an answer with an illustration (that would obviously entail code). If you read through some of my answers, you will note that that pattern is one I use often. I have no problem with any of that.

Comment: Instead, the issue WRT this specific Q is that I don't think the OP is after that. One thing to note is that all the clarifying edits that serve to move the Q *somewhat* away from 'what library & code do I use?' were made by you, not the OP. Even the edited Q still implies that the answer they are after is  '`library(z); mod <- y(data); summary(mod)`'. If you had both, my guess is that the OP would skip the "[technical and wordy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92141/pp-plots-vs-qq-plots/100383#comment621298_100383)" stuff & just look at the code.

Comment: As I said above, another conceptual test that I use to think through whether a Q is on topic, is what if the issue were illustrated, but with software the OP doesn't have? In this case, I think the answer we are describing would be an absolute $0$: The part about statistics is of no interest to the OP, & they would not be able to run the code. So the whole thing would be viewed as a waste.

Comment: By way of contrast, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89968/) is an answer that follows the general pattern, describing a plot, & illustrating it, but w/ software to which I don't have access (& can't even read). Nonetheless, I thought it was quite helpful to me.

Comment: @gung This OP never posted on CV before and is obviously unfamiliar with our rules. When I see a suboptimal Q that I consider potentially interesting (also for others and for future readers), I'd rather edit it to make it comply with our guidelines, than close as not complying. This was my intention here. Just trying to "save" a potentially interesting thread.

Comment: I'm not blaming you for trying, @amoeba. I hope I didn't give you that impression.

Comment: @gung whoa, it must have taken some ...guts to define your nice answer about the difference btw pp-plots and qq-plots "technical & wordy". There's literally not a single equation in it.

Comment: @gung one last comment and then I'll refrain from intervening on this topic anymore: you and amoeba have already discussed it at length, and you're users with way more experience than me. I tend to agree with gung that the OP seems to be interested in code only, but a "method + a little code" answer would be useful to other users. Does this make a difference in deciding if the Q is on-topic or off-topic? Not a rhetorical question.

Comment: Exactly my point @DeltaIV: I often tend to think about other users more than about OP.

Comment: That's an excellent question, @DeltaIV. It has kept coming up in my thinking as amoeba & I have been discussing this. I'm not sure what the answer is (although implicitly I've been saying 'no' by not reopening). It may be worth a separate meta thread to hash out. The underlying issue goes farther than this thread. What is 1 answer will be better for the asker, but a different answer will be better for posterity, eg?

Comment: Ok, I'll ask it. I don't have time now to write a nice question (and I actually need to write two of them), so it will be short, but hopefully good.